# Camera Freeze: How to reinitialise camera component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

Took photo using camera and then navigated to another page where there is a back button, on click event I am again navigating to camera but this time camera freezes but I am able to click a another photo.

Observed that camera freezes if navigation flow is camera => other component (eg. camera clicked picture view) => camera.

And if navigation flow is other component (eg. anything but not camera) => camera, then camera freeze is not occurring. May be need to kill the camera thing and then navigation should occur.

Package thread: [react-native-camera-kit](https://github.com/wix/react-native-camera-kit/issues/156)

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the problem but after several searches on the internet I solved it using `componentDidMount`

React-navigation does not unmount components when switching between tabs. So when you leave and return back to the screen with the camera component it will just be black view. So a good solution is to use `componentDidMount` and added two listeners `willFocus` and `willBlur` to help you mount and unmount the views.

```
componentDidMount() {
   const { navigation } = this.props;
   navigation.addListener('willFocus', () =>
     this.setState({ focusedScreen: true })
   );
   navigation.addListener('willBlur', () =>
     this.setState({ focusedScreen: false })
   );
 }




    render() {
        const { isPermitted, focusedScreen } = this.state;
        if (isPermitted === null) {
          return (<View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Text>Error</Text>
          </View>);
        } else if (isPermitted === false) {
          return (<View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" style={{color:'blue', fontSize:30}} />
            <Text>No Acceas to camera</Text>
          </View>);
        } else if (focusedScreen){
          return ( <View>
            <FullPageLoader isVisible={this.state.isLoader} TextToShow={this.state.loaderText} />
            <CameraKitCameraScreen
            actions={{ leftButtonText: <Icon name='close' style={{color:'white',fontSize:30}}/>,rightButtonText: <Icon name='images' style={{color:'white',fontSize:40}}/> }}
            onBottomButtonPressed={event => this.onBottomButtonPressed(event)}
            ref= {(cam) => {
              this.camera = cam;
            }}
            flashImages={{
              on: require('./img/flashon.png'),
              off: require('./img/flashoff.png'),
              auto: require('./img/flashauto.png'),
            }}
            TopTitle={this.state.title}
            cameraFlipImage={require('./img/flip-camera.png')}
            captureButtonImage={require('./img/capture.png')}
            cameraOptions={{
              flashMode: 'auto',             // on/off/auto(default)
              focusMode: 'on',               // off/on(default)
              zoomMode: 'on',                // off/on(default)
              ratioOverlayColor: '#00000077'
            }}
            style={{height:'100%'}}
          />
          </View>);
        }else{
          return (<Text>Camera Error</Text>);
        }
      }
```

Reference : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/react-navigation.md

Answer (score 0):

For those using Expo and React Native functional components, this gets  even more complicated.

For those who are first arriving, the problem is that React Native screens don't destroy the camera on leave. You can create multiple camera screens, but when you return to a previous camera screen, the preview appears to freeze because the camera on that screen never re-initializes.

My solution was to create a single camera and to switch UI conditionally render components  around it to suit the needs of the UI.

Something like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

export default function App() {

   const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState(false);
   const [cameraMode1, setCameraMode1] = useState(true);

   const takePicture = async () => {
        if (cameraMode1) {
           alert("Picture mode 1");
           setCameraMode1(false);
        } else {
           alert("Picture mode 2");
           setCameraMode1(true);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getCameraStatus() {
            const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
            setHasCameraPermission(status == 'granted');
        }
        getCameraStatus();
    }, [hasCameraPermission]);

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <Camera
              style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject]}
        />
        {cameraMode1 ?
        <Button
            title="Camera Mode 1"
            onPress={() => { takePicture() }}
        />
        :
        <Button
            title="Camera Mode 2"
            onPress={() => { takePicture() }}
        />
        }
       </View>
    );
}
```

You can [Test out this code on Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@backupbrain/dabc89)